# Programmatically hook up events to methods?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, events

Is there a way to hookup a button click to a method programmatically? It would be like imitating the CTRL+CLICK in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out UIControl, what UIButton inherits from.  Specifically this method:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

The action is the method you want to be invoked, and controlEvents represents the events that the action method should be called for, e.g. UIControlEventTouchUpInside for a click.